# Accessing WordPress user meta array values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Here is what I am using to retrieve some custom user meta in WordPress:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$key = 'submit_data_' . $cat;
$single = true;
$viewed = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
```

And `var_dump($viewed);` returns this:

```
array(2) { 
["catalog_number"]=> string(6) "VIZ025" 
["sub_date"]=> string(19) "2015-09-29 06:40:18" 
}
```

When I try to access the values using `$viewed["catalog_number"]` I get an illegal offset warning which I understand but then using something like `$viewed[0]` returns nothing.

How do I access the values e.g. "VIZ025" and the date string?

I need to use the values in some conditionals like this:

```
<?php if($viewed["catalog_number"] == $cat) { 
 // stuff here
} ?>
```

### Updated

`var_dump($viewed, $viewed['catalog_number']);` returns this:

```
 array(2) { ["catalog_number"]=> string(6) "VIZ025"
["sub_date"]=> string(19) "2015-09-29 06:40:18" } string(6) "VIZ025"
```

### Solved

I needed to use isset as new visitors would not have this in the user meta tables yet:

```
if (isset($viewed['catalog_number'])) {
 $ccat = $viewed['catalog_number'];
}
```

This is a valuable lesson: always make sure there is a value to access.

Comment: `$viewed["catalog_number"]` should be good

Comment: After php 5.4 I get a illegal offset warning using that so I need another solution. The `string(6)` is part of the array value which is why I am getting the warning (I think).

Comment: `var_dump($viewed, $viewed['catalog_number']);` what does it show?

Comment: So `$viewed['catalog_number']` return `VIZ025`. What's your problem?

Comment: You were right - my code was fine...I just needed to check if there was actually a value there. Question updated. Thanks!

Comment: You can answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use isset as new visitors would not have this in the user meta tables yet:

```
if (isset($viewed['catalog_number'])) {
 $ccat = $viewed['catalog_number'];
}
```

This is a valuable lesson: always make sure there is a value to access.